# MySQL hell... can't connect to database /tmp/mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sockets, mysql.sock, osx-server

**Update:** I've STOPPED the older mysql process which was running and causing some confusion. Now I think I have only the newer (5.1.40) version running. BUT, it's pointing to the wrong data file. It's pointing to a default install data file and I'd like it to point to the existing data file in `/var/mysql`. Here's a portion of /etc/my.cnf

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

this is pointing to the older mysql.sock. I can't seem to find in the directory tree of the newer MySQL install?!? unless it's somewhere obscure.

Anyone help? Basically I installed a newer MySQL and now need to get this new version to launch with my existing data.  And sort out this mysql.sock thing....

---

I've recently updated MySQL on Mac OS X Server and am having a hell of a time connecting to it from a rails app. or consistently from the command-line for that matter.

i'm sure this is an obvious error on my part but I only have moderate command-line experience so hoping someone can help...

also related is my rails app no longer can connect. Failing to connect via `/tmp/mysql.sock` but I'm not sure why it's looking there because there is no mysql.sock in /tmp and I don't know what/where it should be....

**Edit:** adding results from mysql_config --sockets

```
$ mysql_config --sockets
Usage: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch ppc -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL]
        --include        [-I/usr/local/mysql/include]
        --libs           [-arch ppc  -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -lm     -lmygcc]
        --libs_r         [-arch ppc  -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm     -lmygcc]
        --plugindir      [/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin]
        --socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [5.1.40]
        --libmysqld-libs [-arch ppc  -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqld -ldl  -lz -lm       -lmygcc]
```

**Edit2** which mysql_config

```
$ which mysql_config
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: Not to be a complete idiot, but I've gotta ask it...are you sure you've run `mysql.server start` from the command line?

Comment: never overestimate me ;-) i'll check... ok. command returns with: `-bash: mysql.server: command not found`. I CAN connect to the 'old' database..and there's an mysqld process so I *assume* one of 'em's running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use different sockets for the server and client. Your Rails is trying to connect to /tmp/mysql.sock, by MySQL is listening on /var/mysql/mysql.sock.

Normally MySQL configuration is stored in /etc/my.cnf, but in your `ps` your output I see socket path is given as a parameter. So really depends on your system's specifics.

Anyway, look in /etc/my.cnf and your database.yml and make sure mysql.sock appears at the same path in both files.

Comment: so, how can I find which socket to use?  can I list them? I'm assuming I want to connect to the one associated with the newer version of MySQL.

Comment: And the newer one installed under /usr/local/mysql? It looks to me you are not running this instance.

Comment: ok. this helped alot. i think what's going on is the Admin tools for OS X Server are keeping my old mysql alive even when i've thought it had been "dead". looking into how to handle that now...

Comment: The default location switched for the `.sock` file between 10.5 and 10.6. Either symlink the new file to the old location, or fix your (ruby|php|mysql) configuration appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't even find the new mysql.sock file so I can't symlink to it. This particular server is running OS X 10.5.8 (if that matters).

Comment: `etc/my.cnf` clearly sets the socket to: `socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock` but for whatever reason typing `$ mysql` says it can't connect via `/tmp/mysql.sock`. where is this getting set?  perhaps the `etc/my.cnf` is for the older MySQL. how can I locate the `my.cnf` that the newer version of MySQL I recently installed is looking for?

Comment: That's configuration for your old instance. Check whether you have `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` or anywhere under `/usr/local/mysql`.

Comment: Also, it looks to me that you are running your new server from inside build directory. Do you think you should do something like `make install` first?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this will completely solve your problem (you may need to fix the socket path as suggested by cababunga), but try `127.0.0.1` to bypass the socket connection and establish a TCP one.

Comment: could you please give me an example of what you mean? i'm really not a master of the command line. i know enough to get around...and get into trouble (obviously) but not sure what you mean by `127.0.0.1` which i know only as the IP of the localhost.

Comment: @Meltemi I mean specifying `host: 127.0.0.1` in the yml file

Answer (score 1):

The function `real_connect` in the Ruby MySQL module actually takes a bunch of parameters:

`real_connect(host,user,password,db,port,socket,flags)`

The one you need to change is the "socket" parameter.  On my Python apps on Mac OS X, I have to set that socket parameter to be `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

So notice, it's not the host you need to change, it's the actual socket.  Is there a `socket:` parameter you can use in your config?

So here's what you can do...

Run the command `mysql_config --socket` on your command line in a terminal in OS X and it should return you the value of the "socket" you need to use (probably `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`).

Then in your database.yml file, make sure you add the line:

`socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock`

I've mostly run into this via Python on OS X and fixed it in a similar fashion, but I'm going to guess that Ruby will give you the same issue.

Comment: thanks for the help! so `mysql_config --socket` returns with `/tmp/mysql.sock`. But there is NO "mysql.sock" in my `/tmp` directory?!?

Comment: Was MySQL up and running when you did the check? I believe the file won't be there unless it is.  You could also try this: `mysql -e \"show variables like 'socket'\"` and look for the `socket` parameter (don't forget to add username/password params if you need them)

Comment: ok. now I have managed to stop the *old* MySQL and get the newer version running! am now able to get something back from `mysql_config --socket` (see above)/ But again it says the socket is `/tmp/mysql.sock` but there is no file of such name in /tmp?!? So not sure what's going on.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you sure that the `mysql_config` command you're running is the one for the new database and not the old?  You might want to do a `which mysql_config` on the command line and double-check.

Comment: I think personally I'd just try both `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock` and `socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock` in the .yml file (one at a time) and see if either one works.

Comment: it appears to be the new mysql_config...  i'm now wondering if maybe the new mysql is not pointing to the right data file?!?