# rake db:create not working for legacy rails app (2.3.5) using MySQL (5.5.28)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a new Rails Developer, and I'm working on a legacy Rails app.  Whenever I run the rake db:create command, I get an error that the database couldn't be created.  I have found many StackOverflow questions related to this, but in troubleshooting nearly all permutations of solutions, I couldn't resolve the issue.

I created the three Dbs (dev, prod, test), created the user with all access privileges to these dbs, and ran `rake db:create`.

I'm running Mac OS X Lion, MySQL 5.5.28, Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7.  Here are my settings

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: adva_development
  username: adva
  password: ****
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Here's the error:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql", "username"=>"adva", "host"=>"localhost", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=>"adva_development", "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock", "password"=>"****"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

I have done the following troubleshooting:

1. Verified user and password are correct, and the user has access to the DB.  (Double checked user access with `SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE Db = 'adva_development' \G;`  User has all privileges.)
2. Verify the socket is correct.  I don't really understand sockets, but I can plainly see it at /tmp/mysql.sock.
3. Checked collation and character set.  I found out I had created the DB in latin charset and collation, so I recreated them.  I ran `show variables like "collation_database";` and `show variables like "character_set_database";` and came back with utf8 and utf8_unicode_ci respectively.
4. I followed the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672756/error-creating-rails-db-using-rake-dbcreate).  After uninstalling mysql gem, I ran the following but came up with the same error:

   ```
   gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64/bin --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
   ```
5. Following Matt's suggestion, here's what a `rake --trace db:create` reveals:

   ```
   ** Invoke db:create (first_time)
   ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
   ** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
   ** Execute rails_env
   ** Execute db:load_config
   ** Execute db:create
   Couldn't create database for {"database"=>"adva_development", "adapter"=>"mysql", "host"=>"127.0.0.1", "password"=>"woof2adva", "username"=>"adva", "encoding"=>"utf8"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
   ```

After 3 days and six or seven hours, I have pretty much run out of options.  I tried various random things, like replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 to no avail.

Could there be something wrong related to my specific environment?  Mac OS X Lion + MySQL 5.5.28?  I plan on trying on setting up everything in a Linux environment.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to run `rake --trace db:create`? It may give you some more details on the error.

Comment: "Verified user and password are correct, and the user has access to the DB" - you mean the user has access to *create* the *non-existent* database? Wording it like this, it sounds like it's not creating it because it already exists?

Comment: Also, at this point, why not just create it yourself and get on with your life? Really, all that matters is that you can do things like `rake db:schema:load` etc.

Comment: @woahdae rake db:schema:load produces another set of errors.  Also, Matt, I put the trace results in the original question.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the sockets are the same for rails client and mysql server? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251009/mysql-hell-cant-connect-to-database-tmp-mysql-sock

Comment: I don't mean to be too simplistic, but I have to ask the "is it plugged in?" question: what happens when you `mysql -u root` and `show databases;`, is adva_development in the list?

Comment: @woahdae When I log in to mysql and type `show databases;`, I get all the proper databases listed.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more specific (again, forgive my if this is known territory). First, type `mysql -u root`. You should see something like `mysql>`. Now, type `show databases;`. This should output a table with the list of existing databases

Comment: @woahdae Ah, I edited at the same time you did, see above.  Thanks.

Comment: Is `adva_development` in that list? If so, `rake db:create` will fail because it already exists (imagine typing this in production by accident, you would *not* want that to go ahead and successfully overwrite your db)

Comment: @woahdae That will be pretty embarrassing if that's the issue.  I somehow figured I would get a different error message if that was the issue.  Here's the error I encounter when I run rake db:schema:load.  `rake aborted!
no such file to load -- /Users/richter/wrinkledog/adva/config/../vendor/adva/engines/adva_cms/boot`
I guess I should search for this file and what it does...

Comment: @woahdae I deleted adva_development and ran rake db:create, I still get the same error ("couldn't create database")!  I actually remember trying this before.  Back to square 1.

Comment: Did you install mysql gem

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing localhost to `127.0.0.1` and removing `socket` to use TCP/IP instead of a local socket.

Or try to verify if your database server uses the same socket as Rails:

`mysqladmin variables | grep socket`

If this doesn't help, then try to connect to the database server with pure Ruby and create a new database:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'

begin
  db = Mysql.new('localhost', 'root', 'yourpassword')
  db.query('create database sample_database;');
rescue Mysql::Error => e
  puts e
ensure
  db.close unless db.nil?
end
```

and see if this runs. You should have mysql gem installed (`gem install mysql`)

Comment: I receive the exact same set of errors using `127.0.0.1` and the socket checks out.  Here's the result: `| socket                                            | /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: Do I type this in irb?  If so, I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql::Error
 from (irb):7`

Comment: Save it into a, say, `test.rb` file and run `ruby test.rb`

Comment: Same error: `test.rb:7: uninitialized constant Mysql::Error (NameError)`  According to woahdae, I shouldn't even be running rake db:create, and rake db:schema:load should work.  I'm contacting my employer about github access to more repositories, because I think the issue with rake db:schema:load might lie there.

Comment: What he means is you should connect to your db server with some mysql client, maybe some graphical one, and create the database manually yourself. To run db:schema:load you need to have a db created. It has nothing to do with git.

Comment: Right, I already created the DB's and manually created them.  rake db:schema:load doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: Uh, ok. I updated my answer again - try installing the mysql gem, if you haven't already. That script works on my machine, connects to the db and creates that database.

Comment: If you run `rake --tasks` you'll see that db:schema:load just loads `db/schema.rb` file. It won't exist in a fresh app.

Comment: It's not a fresh app; it's a legacy app (as I wrote above).  The schema file exists and has content.

Comment: FYI, I deleted adva_development and ran rake db:create, I still get the same error ("couldn't create database")! I actually remember trying this before. So the original question holds.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you running a more recent version of the [mysql gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql).  I ran into this problem with version `2.8`. Upgrading to `2.9` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

change 'localhost' into '127.0.0.1' (loop back address) , hope its works